# Python - how to remove commas, square brackets and quotation marks from list

Tags: python, listview

How do I remove the quote marks and commas and brackets from this result:

```
    encrypt = input("enter your string: ")
    encrypt = encrypt.replace(" ","")
    encrypt_list = [encrypt[i:i+5] for i in range(0, len(encrypt), 5)]
    print (encrypt)
    print (encrypt_list)
```

If the input was: `5 blocks of text test`

The output is:  `['5bloc', 'ksoft', 'extte', 'st']`

I need it to be: `5bloc ksoft extte st`

Comment: I'm not sure I get the question. Are you aware that you have a list of strings and none of those strings contains a comma, bracket or quotation mark? Your expected result is a syntax error. Do you mean the string `'5bloc ksoft extte st'`?

Comment: Briefly: `print(*encrypt_list)`.

Comment: Knowing what the basic types look like is basic research. Please put in a bit more effort before asking a question.

Comment: dataToWrite = ' '.join(map(str, vals))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`str.join`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/stdtypes.html#str.join), like this:

```
>>> s = ' '.join(['5bloc', 'ksoft', 'extte', 'st'])
>>> print(s)
5bloc ksoft extte st
```